In-App High-Quality Voice Downloads for iOS Speech Synthesis
I'm creating an iOS app that uses speech synthesis, but for users to use high-quality voices, they have to go to the iOS settings and manually download the voices themselves.
Is there a way to allow downloading high-quality voices within the app, even in iOS 18?
